# Google Maps iOS SDK Integration not loading maps

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, google-maps, maps

I am using **Google maps iOS SDK** in my iPhone application. I am showing a place mark on the map and it is working fine in my iPhone device **using my apple developer account certificates**. But when i sent build to testing team **using a different Enterprise Apple developer account certificates**(Enterprise account), the maps are not loading up, it only shows the Place mark on a blank screen with the maps loading up.

I have also tried on my iPhone devices with the enterprise apple developer account, and it is not loading the map(Just a Pin on blank screen). But with my own apple developer account certificates, it is working absolutely fine.

I am assuming that the problem is in Enterprise Apple developer account(Might be i have change some settings on Apple developer account for my App Id). I am not able to find out a solution for this.

Can anybody help me out on this? If you need more information on this , please ask me in a comment.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Typically this will happen if you don't have the app bundle id added to your google APIs console. The bundle id (eg., com.myname.appname) is what google uses to verify that an app is allowed to use a certain api key. If you've moved your app from one developer account to another, you've probably changed the bundle id in the process. Fortunately, google allows you to associate multiple bundle ids with a single api key.

To add a new bundle id:

- Verify the bundle id you are using in xcode (select the target and look under summary)
- Login to https://code.google.com/apis/console/
- Select "API Access" on the left column
- Select "Edit allowed iOS apps" under the "key for iOS apps" section
- Add the bundle id used in the enterprise build

Comment: You save my day! Thanks a lot. I might give you 1000 upvotes if stackover allows that :)

Comment: You can do that, click on 'start a bounty' link above :P

Comment: @Bharat smartypants

Comment: Great! =))))))))

Comment: NOT WORK FOR ME

Answer (score 8):

### Also possible

For me, I just simply haven't enabled the SDK for iOS.

To make sure you have:

1. Go to your [console](https://console.developers.google.com/) with your selected project.
2. Navigate to the API Library page

[image]

3. Click on Maps SDK for iOS

[image]

4. Press the enable button (it's not there any longer after it's enabled.. so make sure that it says API Enabled.

[image]

Note:
I know this answer doesn't contribute to the specific question... but it fits the title!

Comment: This works. I created API keys but didn't enable this yet.