# Cordova iOs Google Maps map Blank on Appstore

Tags: ios, iphone, google-maps, cordova

i have created an iPhone App with cordova and the google maps Plugin for Cordova (https://github.com/wf9a5m75/phonegap-googlemaps-plugin). I entered the API Key for Ios and on the Emulator it works great. Also when i test it on my iPhone it works. So i submitted the app to the AppStore and after it gets reviewed i downloaded it from the Appstore but the Map is blank. There are no Control Elements like when the API Key is wrong. Now my question is what i should do now?

I tried:

```
<access origin="*" />
```

- Changing Bundle Identifier
- Check API Key
- Take the IPA and installed it manually on a iPhone/iPad (the Map works)

So i think the Probleme must came from Apple or do i see that wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi, thank you for using my plugin. Could you tell me your app on the app store?

Comment: Vier- & Marschlande App - de.vum-app.vum

Answer (score 2):

The phonegap-googlemaps-plugin is not subjected by `<access origin="*" />`, because the Google Maps SDK for iOS connects to the internet directly.

Typically the bundle identifier and the API key are mismatch.
[Google Maps iOS SDK Integration not loading maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17977420/google-maps-ios-sdk-integration-not-loading-maps#17978321)

Is there any error message in Xcode?

Comment: In xcode it works corectly and no errors are displayed. And if the Api Key would be wrong, then there would be the control elements like zoom or directions.

Comment: Right. And I confirmed your app does not output the API key mismatch error. (You can confirm NSLog output using DEVICES  http://goo.gl/Sjb7AE)

Comment: It means the bundle identifier and the api key are matched.

Comment: Right. So far so good. Maybe i whould send it to Apple once more, maybe there was sth. wrong when Archiving it for Apple. Because when i run my App from xCode it works correctly ? Or what should i do now? The Device Logs are clean.

Comment: Before sending to Apple again, add console.log() for every function. That might be helpful for debug again after released.

Comment: This is a god Idea! I found out that is sporadic because sometimes it works on some iPhones and iPads and on some it doesn't work. What is the Plugin doing exactly when the Map gets called?

Comment: When you call map.getMap(), the plugin creates a mapview, and place it under the browser view.

Comment: Thank you for your Tip Maybe i just recode it and then i send it again to Apple.

Comment: Hi, I updated your app. It seems the problem is solved. Congratulation!