# Google Maps iOS SDK: Map not loading

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

I am new to iOS development and am trying out a simple app using Google Maps SDK. I am following the steps listed on [Google Maps Getting Started guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/start#step_1_get_the_latest_version_of_xcode).

I have seen the similar question: 
[Google Maps iOS SDK Integration not loading maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17977420/google-maps-ios-sdk-integration-not-loading-maps) 
where the problem is with bundle ID. I made sure it is not the case for me.

I already spent 3 days trying new app from scratch.

- I created a new api key, added my bundle ID.
- I added API key:

  ```
  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
      // Override point for customization after application launch.
      GMSServices.provideAPIKey("MYKEY")
      return true
  }
  ```
- Following is the ViewController.swift:

  ```
  import UIKit
  import GoogleMaps

  class ViewController: UIViewController {

      override func viewDidLoad() {
          super.viewDidLoad()
          // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
          let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: -33.86, longitude: 151.20, zoom: 6.0)
          let mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect.zero, camera: camera)
          view = mapView

          let marker = GMSMarker()
          marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -33.86, longitude: 151.20)
          marker.title = "Sydney"
          marker.snippet = "Australia"
          marker.map = mapView
      }

  }
  ```

I ran it on simulator and real phone. 
I get the marker and Google logo but no map. Can some one give some clues?

Comment: Have you downloaded the GoogleInfo.plist and added to the target in your project?

Comment: They are problem in your code. one you are setting rect of map and second you have to add map as subview. You can follow this tutorial

https://www.raywenderlich.com/109888/google-maps-ios-sdk-tutorial

Comment: Thanks for pointers - I did not add .plist and the I was just following google getting started guide. I will try your suggestions and will get back ..

Comment: @Aks, i am not using firebase. I do not find how to get GoogleService-Info.plist for google maps.

Comment: @Waqas, The link you sent seem very old and i do not find MapViewController in the object library. I think its got to do with the api key, Any way to debug in google console what is being received and what error it is encountering?

Comment: You will create MapViewController. Download the finalize code for more detail

Answer (score 29):

Hi I found the issue and fixed the problem.
The problem is with the API key - not code.
Before IOS app, i was trying a sample android map app and i used the same console to create new api key without enabling google maps api for IOS.

Developers console somehow allows to add IOS restrictions on API key even though SDK for IOS is not enabled - because of this, I never thought I need to do anything more.

If you get this error and you already verified bundle ID is current, check the following:

- Go to https://console.developers.google.com
- Click on dashboard
- Click on "Enable APIs and Services" with a + mark on the top of the page.
- Check that you have "Google Maps SDK for iOS" enabled. if it is not, enable it.
- Rerun your app and enjoy :)

-Kal

Comment: God, thank you! I was pulling my hair out. Configuring Google SDKs is the worst! They haven't mentioned it in their docs even.

Comment: This worked for me in late 2019 I was using the Maps SDK `API Key` and not the `iOS key (auto created by Google Service)`.  Using the latter instead of the former made it work for me.

Answer (score 2):

Please make sure you generate the right api key before you run the project for the first time. I faced the similar issue and fixed it by generating and enabling the right APIKey for iOS (and not javascript or android) using this link -- [APIKey for iOS](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/get-api-key)