# Google maps SDK not working on SwiftUI app

Tags: swiftui, uiviewcontroller, sdk, uikit, uiviewcontrollerrepresentable

I've followed the [steps](https://developers.google.com/codelabs/maps-platform/maps-platform-101-swift#0) of adding a map to my iOS app and then created a struct to "bridge" between swiftUI and UIkit but for some reason when I call the struct nothing would show whatsoever.

This is my viewcontroller:

```
import CoreLocation
import UIKit
import GoogleMaps

class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate{
    
    let manager = CLLocationManager()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        manager.delegate = self
        manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        manager.startUpdatingLocation()
        
        GMSServices.provideAPIKey("xxx")
        
        
        print("License: \n\n\(GMSServices.openSourceLicenseInfo())")
    }
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        guard let location = locations.first else {
            return
        }
        
        let coordinate = location .coordinate
        let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: coordinate.latitude, longitude: coordinate.longitude, zoom: 6.0)
        let mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: view.frame, camera: camera)
        view.addSubview(mapView)

        let marker = GMSMarker()
        marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -coordinate.latitude, longitude: coordinate.longitude)
        marker.title = "Sydney"
        marker.snippet = "Australia"
        marker.map = mapView
        
    }
}
```

and this is the struct created in my content view:

```
struct YourViewControllerView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {

    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> ViewController {
        return ViewController()
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: ViewController, context: Context) {
       
    }

}
```

[I've searched for similar problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46753517/google-maps-ios-sdk-map-not-loading) but everyone else had the problem of the map not *loading* (marker and google logo still show), whereas in my case nothing shows on the screen at all.

Just to reiterate, my Maps SDK for iOS is enabled.

I've been trying to find a solution for a week now so help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You aren't giving any frame to the subview you add.

Comment: @jnpdx sorry if this is a no brainer but can you elaborate. How would I give the subview a frame?

Comment: You may want to read about autolayout, constraints, etc. You can also literally call `.frame = ...` but that won't adjust things when the view resizes.

Comment: so does that mean that I should adjust my content view or viewcontroller?

Comment: I don’t understand the question. You need to add a frame to your mapview

Comment: @jnpdx how do i do that?

Comment: See my previous comment about what to search for or try.